# Docker compose with two files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two `docker-compose.yml` files in separate folders.

I'd like to run the two of them in the same command, in order for the services from both to be able to talk to each other.

However, when I go to the lowest common path ancestor and try to run `docker-compose` with both files, here is what happens:

```
$ docker-compose -f ./api-folder/docker-compose.yml -f ./front-folder/docker-compose.yml up -d
ERROR: build path /projects/front-folder/api either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.

$ docker-compose -f ./front-folder/docker-compose.yml -f ./api-folder/docker-compose.yml up -d
ERROR: build path /projects/api-folder/app either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

Here are the two `docker-compose.yml` files:

**/projects/front-folder/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:

    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./app
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: 'dev'
        ports:
            - "4400:4400"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app

    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - ./logs:/usr/local/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - app
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

**/projects/api-folder/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:

    api:
        restart: always
        build: ./api
        expose:
            - "4600"
        volumes:
            - ./api:/usr/src/app
            - ./logs:/logs

    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - ./logs:/usr/local/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - api
        ports:
            - "81:80"
        networks:
            - hackerz
```

And the directory structure:

```
- /projects
    - /front-folder
        - /app
            Dockerfile
        - /nginx
            Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
    - /api-folder
        - /api
            Dockerfile
        - /nginx
            Dockerfile
        docker-compose.yml
```

I'm guessing the problem is with the `build` paths, but what I don't understand is:

- Why Docker insists on searching `build: ./api` in `/front-folder` or the other way around?
- How to circumvent this problem and be able to run both files together?

Comment: Just curious -- why aren't you putting all of the services into a single Docker Compose file? Also, I might be wrong about this, but you might be able to keep them separate, and simply put all of the containers inside a Docker network. Have you already tried that?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan yep I tried but didn't manage to set it up, for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

DOCKERFILE
Alternate Dockerfile.

Compose uses an alternate file to build with. A build path must also be specified.

```
service3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
```

**docker compose build giving custom file**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how compose works (by design). See my comment here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3530#issuecomment-222490501.